# Launching Finder in macOS 10.15, Catalina, with a shortcut

Tags: finder, catalina

I've previously used shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to launch new finder windows. In macOS 10.15, Catalina, this has changed in a way that search is now mandatory and I cannot select View -> Show sidebar (it is disabled).

Is there a way to launch new Finder window with keyboard or a way to get old behavior back?

Edit: This seems to be problem in this computer. I have access also to another Catalina running macbook where <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> works as before.

Comment: See if you assigned shortcuts to something else in keyboard preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was simple as `View -> Show Toolbar`. Finder cannot show sidebar if toolbar is not enabled. Maybe catalina upgrade changed this, or I have accidentally pressed shortcut to hide toolbar.